# Yii2 Delete record with request POST

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

How can I remove a record from the database (MySQL) using request POST?

In view:

```
<a href="<?= Url::to(['user/delete', 'id' => Html::encode($user->id)]) ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

In controller:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model = User::findOne($id);

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->delete();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'User deleted successfully');
    }

    return $this->redirect(['user/index']);
}
```

This code deletes only with request GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set delete button like this

```
<?= Html::a('Delete', ['user/delete', 'id' => $user->id], [
                'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                'data-confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
                'data-method' => 'post',
            ]) ?>
```

And Html class is

use yii\helpers\Html;